# How to enable TUI for gdb on Debian 9?

Tags: debian, gdb

When debugging it is often helpful to loot at assembly, but on Debian 9 when I try `layout asm` I get:

`Undefined command: "layout".  Try "help".`

According to some internet research it seems like I need to have TUI enabled, but I'm not sure how to enable or install it.

Comment: Does `tui enable` then `layout asm` work?

Comment: @kemotep I get `Undefined command: "tui"`

Comment: You need to be in a gdb console. Invoke your program using `gdb` or `gdb [name of the executable you wish to debug]`. You can also launch `gdb` with `--tui` to immediately enter TUI mode. If this is unsupported then your install of `gdb` was not configured with TUI support and you will need to reinstall or recompile `gdb` to include these features.

Comment: What's the first line of the output of `gdb --version` ?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick GNU gdb (Debian 7.12-6) 7.12.0.20161007-git

Comment: What is the output of `uname -a` ? On my Debian 9 x86_64, that version of gdb offers both the tui and layout commands. Maybe you're on some other architecture?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Hmm, interesting, I didn't do anything special to install it, anyway, `uname -a` gives:
`Linux MAXIM-DEB9 4.9.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u5 (2017-09-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: OK, I reproduced this. Installing Debian 9 from the netinst iso installs the `gdb-minimal` package, which doesn't have tui or python support. Do `sudo apt install gdb` to get the full version. This will also remove gdb-minimal.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Tanks, that worked, if you give this as answer I can upvote and mark it as answered

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default installation from Debian 9's netinst ISO doesn't include gdb or C or C++ compilers. A user would typically run `apt install build-essential gdb` to install them.

In certain circumstances - I could reproduce this by using the netinst ISO and choosing to install KDE - the `gdb-minimal` package will be installed, which provides a gdb that doesn't include TUI (or python).

```
mp@debian9$ apt-rdepends -r gdb-minimal
gdb-minimal
  Reverse Depends: plasma-workspace (4:5.8.6-2.1+deb9u1)
plasma-workspace
  Reverse Depends: kde-plasma-desktop (>= 5:92)
  ...
kde-plasma-desktop
  Reverse Depends: kde-full (>= 5:92)
  Reverse Depends: kde-standard (>= 5:92)
```

It looks like you have this.

Running `apt install gdb` will remove `gdb-minimal` and install the full gdb.